# On correct use of comma

Tags: punctuation

Should there be a comma after ***you*** in the following sentence?

> If the afternoon works best for you, please let me know and I will try to adjust my schedule.

Comment: The way I read it yes.  For me it's a natural place for a slight pause.

Comment: It's not required, but it fits well.  It's a matter of personal style, and of whether you would pause there in speaking.  Others might choose to put a comma after "know".  That wouldn't be wrong either.

Comment: While this question **could** simply get the answer "Yes, it's correct," there is no reason why an answer might not be given which explains how the different clauses work.

Comment: As you can see, native speakers ***hear*** commas (they often call them "pauses", although there isn't any actual pause, but rather an intonation change). If you hear them in the speech, use them. This means that, like the _a/an_ rule, the comma rule refers to pronunciation, not meaning, grammar, or vocabulary.

Answer (score 1):

The convention for punctuating conditionals like this is to put a comma between the two clauses when the *if*-clause occurs first, and not to use one when the result-clause occurs first. So the two versions of the Original Posters sentence would theoretically be punctuated thus:

- If the afternoon works best for you, please let me know and I will try to adjust my schedule.
- Please let me know if the afternoon works best for you and I will try to adjust my schedule.

In other words the Original Poster's version is punctuated in accordance with the prevailing conventions. However, comma usage is often in reality more a question of personal taste than a question of "rules" and many modern writers omit commas that would once have been thought to be compulsory.

**Note**: The second version of the sentence there would not be a good one to use. The reason being that the *if*-clause could be interpreted as a content clause instead of as a conditional antecedent. In other words it could be translated as "*Please let me know whether the afternoon works best for you ...*".

Comment: +1, good catch on the ambiguous meaning of that 2nd version! :)